# react-scripts-ts not installing ts-jest in travis

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, docker, travis-ci

I'm trying to use Travis CI with my Dockerized React app, but whenever Travis runs `npm test` I get the error:

`Cannot find module 'ts-jest' from 'setupTests.ts' at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/react-scripts-ts/node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:179:17) at Object.<anonymous> (src/setupTests.ts:1:103).`

`npm install` doesn't give any errors though.

The full stack trace + the build process is over [here](https://travis-ci.org/DovidM/words-with-friends/builds/321586028) and the code is [here](https://github.com/DovidM/words-with-friends/tree/travis)

I'm not sure if this is a problem with React, as I'm trying out Docker and Travis for the first time but the error seems to be coming from `react-scripts-ts`. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try manually install ts-jest module `npm i -D ts-jest`.

Comment: @EduardJacko That seems to lead into a [rabbit hole](https://travis-ci.org/DovidM/words-with-friends/builds/321652647)

Comment: Maybe stupid question but are you running npm install at all? Doesn’t seems like. I didn’t work with docker for long time, but I can’t see installing any node dependencies in the log

Comment: @EduardJacko Yes, it’s folded over but on line 486 npm install is ran

Comment: Have you tried running the test suite?

Comment: @JasonAllshorn The test suite runs correctly on my local machine, but the ts-jest error seems to be preventing it from running in travis